# How to remove capitalization in Twenty Fourteen theme in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

An ugly thing in the Twenty Fourteen theme of Wordpress is that all titles are capitalized. How can I disable this capitalization?

I would prefer that this change is done in the [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and not in the main theme, so that updates won't affect the main theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `text-transform: uppercase;` style to `text-transform: none;` in the `.entry-title` class, will remove the capitalisation in the titles.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me where this should be changed?

Comment: In the styles.css file

Comment: I used the plugin "My Custom CSS" and it worked with that. Thanks for the help.